# Here maps - IOS SDK hybrid plus v2.1 doesn't works correct in iPad air with IOS 8

Tags: ios8, here-api

Is the Here IOS SDK hybrid plus v2.1 works fine in iPad air with ios 8?
The navigation in the demo doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be resolved in IOS SDK hybrid plus v 2.1.1